# How to change type of list to str?

Tags: python, json, string, list

I am extracting a list from html of a web page in the format

```
lst = '["a","b","c"]' # (type <str>)
```

The data type of the above is **str** and I want it to convert to a python **list type** , somthing like this

```
lst = ["a","b","c"]  #(type <list>)
```

I can obtain the above by

```
lst = lst[1:-1].replace('"','').split(',')
```

But as the actual value of a,b &c is quite long and complex(contains long html text), I can't be dependent on the above method.

I also tried doing it with json module and using `json.loads(lst)` , that is giving the below exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Any way of converting to list in Python?

Edit: The actual value of the list is:
    `['reqlistitem.no','reqlistitem.applyonlinejobdesc','reqlistitem.no','reqlistitem.referjobdesc','reqlistitem.applyemailsubjectapplication','reqlistitem.applyemailjobdesc','reqlistitem.no','reqlistitem.addedtojobcart','reqlistitem.displayjobcartactionjobdesc','reqlistitem.shareURL','reqlistitem.title','reqlistitem.shareable','reqlistitem.title','reqlistitem.contestnumber','reqlistitem.contestnumber','reqlistitem.description','reqlistitem.description','reqlistitem.primarylocation','reqlistitem.primarylocation','reqlistitem.otherlocations','reqlistitem.jobschedule','reqlistitem.jobschedule','reqlistitem.jobfield','reqlistitem.jobfield','reqlistitem.displayreferfriendaction','reqlistitem.no','reqlistitem.no','reqlistitem.applyonlinejobdesc','reqlistitem.no','reqlistitem.referjobdesc','reqlistitem.applyemailsubjectapplication','reqlistitem.applyemailjobdesc','reqlistitem.no','reqlistitem.addedtojobcart','reqlistitem.displayjobcartactionjobdesc','reqlistitem.shareURL','reqlistitem.title','reqlistitem.shareable']`

Comment: You need to show the actual code and data you are using. `json.loads(lst)` works fine if `lst` is as you have shown it above.

Comment: I have edited the actual value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are looking for `literal_eval`:

```
import ast

string = '["a","b","c"]'

print ast.literal_eval(string) # ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your sample string is the single quotes. The JSON standard requires double quotes.

If you change the single quotes to double quotes, it will work. An easy way is to use `str.replace()`:

```
import json
s = "['reqlistitem.no','reqlistitem.applyonlinejobdesc','reqlistitem.no']"
json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))
#[u'reqlistitem.no', u'reqlistitem.applyonlinejobdesc', u'reqlistitem.no']
```

Comment: Although this will work, but I have quite a few list like this, which have other values that contains ' , so replacing will not work in those cases.